# The result of grep isn't as expected in some scenarios

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, grep

Question 1：

> filename: testfile
>
> one line string in file: test my file

Execute below command:

> $ grep "test ./testfile

Result as below:

> test my file

My question is why grep with pattern ***"test*** match the content ***test my file*** in file?

Question 2:

> ssh $host "grep "test1 test2" /home/bob -R"
>
> grep: test2: No such file or directory

My question is why grep regard the 2nd section in "test1 test2" as a filename?

P.S.

When I use back slash to escape the quote in question 2, the output of command seems to be correct.

> ssh $host "grep \"test1 test2\" /home/bob -R"

Answer (score 2):

> ssh $host "grep "test1 test2" /home/bob -R"
>
> grep: test2: No such file or directory

You are getting this error, because shell got confused with where `"` is ending. Due to that `grep` assumed that `test1` as pattern and `test2` as a file. Then it is trying to find a file `test2` which doesn't exist. You have to use like :

```
ssh $host 'grep "test1 test2" /home/bob -R'
```